# Handling Infrequently Occurring Categorical Variables

Tags: r, logistic, categorical-data, data-mining, categorical-encoding

I'm dealing with some data where there are some infrequently occuring categorical variables related to a binary prediction target.

For example marketing partners... some send 1000s of leads but many others send less than 10 a minuscule number in a data set with 20K+ examples.

Typically, we deal with this by grouping all the infrequently occurring partners under the variable "Else" and using this as the reference category in logistic regression.

I'm wondering what the pros and cons are of handling the issue like this and if there is a better way to deal with it in pre-processing phase.